# Google Analytics Opt Out for mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, tracking, google-analytics

The [Google Analytics Opt Out](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) Browser Add-ons are  very useful way to shield our browsing from contributing to our clients analytics data.  The link does not work for mobile devices.  Are there any plugins, extensions, or apps available for iOS and Android to block Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

This post gives a few ideas:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/how-do-you-exclude-yourself-from-google-analytics-on-your-website-using-cookies

A variation on what they have..

Where they suggest custom cookie values, you could create a page on the website that sets that value e.g. www.mysite.com/opt-out , bookmark and always use that link first and all visits from that user can easily be excluded. It does rely on starting on that particular page though.